# Flask test_client removes query string parameters

Tags: python, testing, flask

I am using Flask to create a couple of very simple services. From outside testing (using HTTPie) parameters through querystring are getting to the service.

But if I am using something like.

```
    data = {
        'param1': 'somevalue1',
        'param2': 'somevalue2'}

    response = self.client.get(url_for("api.my-service", **data))
```

I can see the correct URI being created:

```
http://localhost:5000/api1.0/my-service?param1=somevalue1&param2=somevalue2
```

when I breakpoint into the service:

```
request.args
```

is actually empty.

`self.client` is created by calling `app.test_client()` on my configured Flask application.

Anyone has any idea why anything after `?` is being thrown away or how to work around it while still using `test_client`?

Answer (score 39):

I've just found out a workaround.

Make

```
data = {
    'param1': 'somevalue1',
    'param2': 'somevalue2'}

response = self.client.get(url_for("api.my-service", **data))
```

into this:

```
data = {
    'param1': 'somevalue1',
    'param2': 'somevalue2'}

response = self.client.get(url_for("api.my-service"), query_string = data)
```

This works but seems a bit unintuitive, and debugging there is a place where the provided query string in the URI is thrown away ....

But anyway this works for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I ran into this too. There's an open issue about this in the flask [github repository](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/801). It appears this is intended behavior. From a response in the issue thread:

*mitsuhiko commented on Jul 24, 2013

That's currently intended behavior. The first parameter to the test client should be a relative url. If it's not, then the parameters are removed as it's treated as if it was url joined with the second. This works:*

```
>>> from flask import Flask, request
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> app.testing = True
>>> @app.route('/')
... def index():
...  return request.url
... 
>>> c = app.test_client()
>>> c.get('/?foo=bar').data
'http://localhost/?foo=bar'
```

One way to convert your absolute url into a relative url and keep the query string is to use urlparse:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

absolute_url = "http://someurl.com/path/to/endpoint?q=test"
parsed = urlparse(absolute_url)
path = parsed[2] or "/"
query = parsed[4]
relative_url = "{}?{}".format(path, query)

print relative_url
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying any other HTTP Method other than GET

```
response = self.client.patch(url_for("api.my-service"), query_string=data,
                             data="{}")
```

`data="{}"` or `data=json.dumps({})` should be there, even if there is no content in the body. Otherwise, it results in BAD Request.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use the client within `with` statements:

```
with app.app_context():
    with app.test_request_context():
        with app.test_client() as client:
            client.get(...)
```

instead of

```
client = app.test_client()
client.get(...)
```

I put the creation of the test client in a fixture, so that it is "automatically" created for each test method:

```
from my_back_end import MyBackEnd

sut = None
app = None
client = None

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def before_each():
    global sut, app, client
    sut = MyBackEnd()
    app = sut.create_application('frontEndPathMock')
    with app.app_context():
        with app.test_request_context():                
            with app.test_client() as client:
                yield
```